# Java override specific method a()

Tags: java, overriding

How do I chose which function to override?
There are 2 functions called a() but I only want to override the one with the int(or string).

Code:

```java
public class SuperClass {

    public void a(String string) {
        //Do something
    }

    public void a(int integer) {
        //Do something
    }

}
```

```java
public class NotSoSuperClass extends SuperClass {

    @Override
    public void a(/*Only for the string*/) {
        //Do something else
    }

}
```

Comment: an override essentially means that you are using the same method signature. So if you want to override the String version, write an method with the same type as argument and vice versa for int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it by specifying the parameter of type which you want to override like this

```
 @Override
 public void a(String string) {
        //Do something else
 }
```

or

```
 @Override
 public void a(int integer) {
        //Do something else
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You go for the method to override:

```
@Override
public void a(String string) {
 ...
```

Done. You simply *do not* override the other method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
@Override
public void a(String string) {
    //Do something else
}
```

a(string) and a(int) are totally different functions to the compiler.  Overriding one should not affect the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!